# Jenkins: After build process boot Jetty and start a test against it

Tags: maven, jenkins, junit, automated-tests, embedded-jetty

How can I design in a best manner a Jenkins job in which a Java project is built by Maven then a Jetty shall boot so in the end a JUnit test class can test against it?

Steps:

1. Build the project by Maven
2. Boot the (embedded) Jetty
3. Execute the tests against the RESTful web service in Jetty

My problem currently is when the Jetty is started then the next command in the shell script cannot be reached because the started Jetty is in the way. :-)

What is the best approach to do stuff like this?

Comment: This could be an doable approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460691/start-jetty-maven-plugin-than-execute-exec-maven-plugin
by using the Maven phases pre-integration-test, integration-test and post-integration-test
Problem: How knows the pre-integration-test phase used by the maven-exec-plugin when the embedded Jetty is up in the end to continue with the tests?

Comment: How are you starting Jetty? There is a [Jetty Maven Plugin](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jetty-maven-plugin.html) which can be used for such things..?

Comment: @khmarbaise: The thing is it is an embedded Jetty and it starts via a main class. I don't think this fits to the Jetty Maven Plugin because this builds up a Jetty from another perspective - maybe on the basis of a WAR.

Comment: The question is what you really like to test furthermore this is not a unit tests it's integration test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reached it with the following maven build settings:

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>sendAPI_CI</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>jetty</id>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>exec</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <async>true</async>
                                    <executable>java</executable>
                                    <arguments>
                                        <argument>-Djson.schemas.location=${project.parent.parent.basedir}/common/target/test/resources/json_schemas/</argument>
                                        <argument>-jar</argument>
                                        <argument>${project.parent.parent.basedir}/facade/target/ams-jar-with-dependencies.jar</argument>
                                    </arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wait-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>wait</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <protocol>http</protocol>
                                    <host>localhost</host>
                                    <port>8181</port>
                                    <file>/swagger</file>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.21.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</testSourceDirectory>
                            <testClassesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/</testClassesDirectory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>com.messaging.async.facade.sendApi.SendApiResourceTest.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

In the *pre-integration-test* phase I use the *[exec-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/index.html)* to start the (embedded) Jetty. Then by the help of the *[wait-maven-plugin](https://github.com/sonatype/wait-maven-plugin)*, in the same Maven phase, we wait until the Jetty is up and this is achieved under the hood by checking if the URL is callable. In the end the *[maven-failsafe-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/index.html)* in the integration-test phase has its mission and starts the integration tests finally against the Jetty. As you can see this is configured within a [Maven profile](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) so in a Jenkins job I can use it there exclusively. Done!